# How to judge direction of motion?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, friction, torque, rotational-kinematics

I have this scenario

> suppose a cylinder is made by joining two symmetrical cones and is given a gentle push on two rails A and B . What will be the motion of cone . Will it turn right or left

[image]

I think that since friction is acting backwards on both the cones but friction on side AB is at an angle while friction on CD is perpendicular to centre o, the torque due to $f_{CD}$> $f_{AB}$  so system tries to rotate in a clockwise sense resulting it in turning right but the answer says its left .

I don't find the mistake in my answer.

Comment: Instead of considering forces, try assuming it rolls without slipping, and think about the distance each side will progress forward as it rolls.

Comment: Fun fact: If you arranged those two cones base-to-base instead of point-to-point, then you would have a reasonable first-order model of an actual [railway _wheel set_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheelset_(rail_transport)#Conical_shape).

Comment: I don't see how the cones put on flat face together gives a railway model @SolomonSlow, could you detail how exactly that happens/ reference for it?

Comment: @Buraian, Actual, steel railroad wheels usually are conic sections, with the narrow ends facing out. Click on the link in my previous comment, and scroll down to "Semi-conical shape" to learn why. (Note: the link was _supposed_ to take you directly to that heading, but I apparently messed it up.)

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for the share  ^^ @SolomonSlow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

All we have to do is assume that the cones dont turn rather move in a straight line but since the distance between the rails is not symmetric the centre of the cone comes closer to one of the rails in comparison to other

This means its centre level has dropped to a certain height as seen in second picture. This actually contradicts our assumption because centre of mass has no external force acting on it and should show no rise or fall. This ultimately means the cone has turned to left to ensure no motion of centre of mass

Answer (score 1):

I will give you 2 hints.

1. Assume that the body never turns .
2. Then at some distance x calculate linear velocity both cones about the centre.

Hints: 1. in pure rolling linear  velocit is given by rw.

2. W is same for both bodies as it is a rigid body.